# Flutter/Dart - "Specify type annotations" with class property of alias type (typedef)

Tags: flutter, dart, annotations, alias, typedef

The Dart linter says "Specify type annotations" on the `FooType` inside the `Bar` class.
But I seemingly do not understand the problem and what I can do to fix it.

```
class FooClass<T> {}

typedef FooType = FooClass<String>;

class Bar {
  FooType get foo => FooClass<String>();
}
```

We are using [Moor](https://pub.dev/packages/moor) in our (pre-null-safety) Flutter app and this problem arose when I wanted to migrate the code and saw that the migration fails at a line where a property was defined like in the example above.

Basically all columns of all tables have this linter message, so I assume, something fundamental is missing.

The linter rule in question:
https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/always_specify_types.html

Comment: I cannot reproduce any warning from the analyzer with `always_specify_types` enabled.  Are you sure that your problem is reproducible with the above code?  If so, with which version of the Dart SDK?

Comment: @jamesdlin Yes, I am sure, because toggleing it lets Android Studio shows that message (if enabled) or not (if disabled). Plus when I am forcing `dart migrate` to migrate the code of my Moor files, which have Moor specific alias types like `TextColumn`, `DateTimeColumn` etc. (which cause the same lint warning), these are the lines at which migrator breaks. If I replace all aliases with their original types (`Column<String>`, `Column<DateTime>` etc.), the migrator won't break. That being said, it might just be a Dart <2.12.0 thing (pre-null-safety).

Comment: Dart 2.12 and earlier didn't support `typedef`s for non-`Function` types.  [More general `typedef`s were introduced in Dart 2.13](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-13-c6d547b57067).